# Как получить путь к файлу через QFileDialog C++ QT в QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Нужно написать программу,которая вызывает из QML диалоговое окно QFileDialog,при этом не используя FileDialog из QtQuick.Dialogs.
То есть нужно написать функцию на C++ с диалогом и чтобы её можно было вызвать из запущенного приложения,которое написано на QML.Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужен класс, который бы инкапсулировал нужный вам функционал, например FileManager, в нем объявляете и определяете слот или Q_INVOKABLE функцию, например, такую:

```
QString FileManager::selectFile()
{
return fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, tr("Save current  project"), lastOpenedDir, tr("Projects (*.prj)"));
}
```

2. Делаете объект этого класса доступным в контексе qml-движка:

```
FileManager fileManager;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("fileManager", &fileManager);
```

3. Теперь можно вызвать из qml:

```
var filename = fileManager.selectFile()
```